# Parse Push is not working with Parse Sever

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I am a newbie on parse server and have been using it with my android app. But I am having trouble with implementing push notifications. I do not know how to get logs so any guidance will be much appreciated! The installation class does not contain any "GCMSenderId" or "deviceToken".

Here is how I set up parse server to implement push notifications.

Parse Sever : 2.2.7

1) Developer Console
a) I create a new project using the new console and clicked on the overflow menu --> Project Info and got my project number.
b) Then I went to the "Credentials" page and clicked on Create Credentials --> Api Key --> Server Key and left everything default and clicked create.
c) I got the key for my project. Let it be "MY_API_KEY".

2) Now I setup my parse server app to use this api key and project number as you can see from the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVaQX.png)

3) Now I setup my android app manifest accordingly as you can see from the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVZY.png)

I also added ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation.saveInBackground();in my app's Application class.

I am trying to send notifications using the parse dashboard

Please provide any help if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to send push notification from parse server you have to implement cloud    code 
    in Javascript or another programming language.
    below is some code in JS to send push notification to a user

```
function(objectids,msg) {
        var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        msg.default="default";
        pushQuery.exists("deviceToken");
        pushQuery.containedIn('userObjectId',objectids);
        try
        {
            Parse.Push.send({
                            where: pushQuery,
                            data: {
                            alert:msg.msgInfo,
                            str:msg,
                            sound:msg.default
                            }
                            }).then(function() {
                                    console.log("push successfully sent");
                                    }, function(error) {
                                    console.log("error while send pn:"+error.code+":"+error.message);
                                    throw "Push Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
                                    });
        }catch(error)
        {
            console.log("error while send pn:"+error.code+":"+error.message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you have to write cloud code .you can prefer another programming language on parse but directly there is no option to send pn from installation table

Comment: I try sending push from the push notifications tab is the open source parse-dashboard

Comment: And I think if everything is setup properly the GCMSenderId and deviceToken in the installation class won't be undefined.